# How to remove "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED" from site with incorrect URLs

Tags: wordpress

Can't seem to find an answer anywhere on the net, so trying here. I'm still a beginner with websites, so I tried All-In-One Migrator to move my WordPress site to a new domain. However, 2 SVGs somehow came with and kept their URL. As now I have the following showing up:

[Console showing failed resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MajeM.png)

[Url of one of the SVGs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLsiZ.png)

The request URL is my old test site. I have tried going into various CSS files to find what is pulling these SVGs, but after removing some lines, nothing seems to help.

Website in question: https://www.wecprojects.com/

Comment: Whenever I need to migrate a website from one server to another, I change the paths in the database. I don't use a plugin for this! You have already verified this link:. Check step 3 --- https://athemes.com/tutorials/move-wordpress-from-local-server-to-live-site/

Comment: @EdrianBiagi thanks, yeah 99% went through fine onto the new site. I don't understand how these files ended up here or why they haven't been removed.